# ionic 4 favorite issue with toString and save data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hi Everyone I am interested to integrate favorite functionality inside my project 
so I get started to transform **ionic 3** project  to **ionic 4** form  :
https://github.com/SoatGroup/ionic3-movie-app
full aritcle here :
 https://soat.developpez.com/tutoriels/mobiles/ionic-3-creer-application-mobile/

I got this error:

```
Client Error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
at FavoriteProviderService.getMovieKey (favorite-provider.service.ts:37)
at FavoriteProviderService.isFavoriteMovie (favorite-provider.service.ts:23)
```

I think it's inside favorite provider :

```
 getMovieKey(movie: IMovie) {

return MOVIE_KEY + movie.id.toString();}
```

the only difference I made, is using http request :

```js
export class DetailsPage implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  movie: IMovie;
  detailsData :IMovie;
  isFavorite: boolean = false;
  
  constructor(public BaseService : BaseService
    ,public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ,public router: Router
    ,private favoriteProviderService:FavoriteProviderService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"];
    this.BaseService.getDetails(this.id).subscribe(response => {
      
      this.detailsData = response;
     
  })
  
    this.fav();
  }//end ngOnInit
  
  fav(){
 this.movie =this.detailsData;
console.log("movie is:", this.movie);
  this.favoriteProviderService.isFavoriteMovie(this.movie)
  .then(value => (this.isFavorite = value)); 
}
  toggleFavorite(): void {
    this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    this.favoriteProviderService.toogleFavoriteMovie(this.movie);
  }
  
}
```

BaseService.ts :

```js
getDetails(id): Observable<IMovie> {
return this.http
  .get<IMovie>('my api here')
  .pipe(
    retry(2),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
}
```

response like this:

```
[{id: 2,title: "somthing",image: "somthing"}]
```

i'm try to check without http request , and it's done testData was put into storage

```js
export class DetailsPage implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  //movie: IMovie;
  //detailsData :IMovie;
  isFavorite: boolean = false;
  testData: IMovie =  {
    id: 2,
 title: "somthing",
    image: "somthing"
    };
  constructor(public BaseService : BaseService
    ,public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ,public router: Router
    ,private favoriteProviderService:FavoriteProviderService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   /* this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"];
    this.BaseService.getDetails(this.id).subscribe(response => {
      
      this.detailsData = response;
     
  })*/
  
    this.fav();
 
  }//end ngOnInit
  
  fav(){
 //this.movie =this.detailsData;
//console.log("movie is:", this.movie);
  this.favoriteProviderService.isFavoriteMovie(this.testData)
  .then(value => (this.isFavorite = value)); 
}
  toggleFavorite(): void {
    this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    this.favoriteProviderService.toogleFavoriteMovie(this.testData);
  }
  
}
```

I need a help to find the solution, i'm really closed ,thanks

Comment: in your getMovieKey function replace return line like this 
`return MOVIE_KEY + (!!movie.id ? movie.id.toString() : "")`

Comment: let me know if it's not work

Comment: @kushalshah yes i'm already trying something like this and it work 
but by result all details movies look marked and when you go to favorite page you'll see the first one bookmark item

Comment: @kushalshah the key in local storage must be unique,so MOVIE_KEY in my example must look like "movie_2" in your example i got  "movie_"

Comment: Because of there is no value in movie.id, let me know when you call getaMovieKey(movie); in components?and what are you passing into parameters?

Comment: @kushalshah getaMovieKey(movie); it is in favorite provider

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
getMovieKey(movie: IMovie) {

    return MOVIE_KEY +(movie.id+'');
}
```